# In what circumstances mergesort is faster than selection sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Doing a calculation according to RAM model, gives that the number of elements that can be more efficiently sorted using selection sort and less efficiently sorted using mergesort, is very low (n << 500000). But, when I tried to test this, I found that selection sort sorted an array of 500000 elements in 3 minutes and 11 seconds and mergesort did it in 6 minutes and 44 seconds. I am sure that implementation of both the algorithms is correct. What's happening? Please EXPLAIN.

Sorry, I am really late to edit this. I lost the network connection.

So here is my mergesort:

```
public class MergeSort {

    // temp array
    public static int temp[];

    public static void merge(int a[], int low, int mid, int high)
    {
       temp = new int [a.length];
       for(int i = low; i <= high; i++)
           temp[i] = a[i];

       int i = low;
       int j = mid + 1;
       int k = low;

       while(i <= mid && j <= high)
       {
           if(temp[i] <= temp[j])
           {
               a[k] = temp[i];
               i++;
           }

           else
           {
               a[k] = temp[j];
               j++;
           }

           k++;
       }

       while(i <= mid)
       {
           a[k] = temp[i];
           k++;
           i++;
       }
    }

    public static void sort(int a[], int low, int high)
    {
        if(low < high)
        {
            int middle = (low + high) / 2;

            // sort the left half
            sort(a, low, middle);

            // sort the right half
            sort(a, middle + 1, high);

            // merge parts
            merge(a, low, middle, high);
        }
    }
}
```

and my selection sort:

```
public static int[] selSort(int a[])
{
    int length = a.length;
    int temp[] = new int [length];

    System.arraycopy(a, 0, temp, 0, length);

    for(int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
    {
        int smIndex = i;

        for(int cIndex = i + 1; cIndex < length; ++cIndex)
            if(temp[cIndex] < temp[smIndex])
                smIndex = cIndex;

        int t = temp[smIndex];
        temp[smIndex] = temp[i];
        temp[i] = t;
    }

    return temp;
}
```

In selection sort, I am duplicating the array for a reason.

Comment: http://www.titrias.com/ultimate-sorting-algorithms-comparison/

Comment: Hello Rahul. I visited the link and clearly in the table, mergesort is faster than selection sort even if the array size is as low as 10000. But that's not happening in my computer.

Comment: `I am sure that implementation of both the algorithms is correct.` May be then you can show us your implementation.

Comment: *"I am sure that implementation of both the algorithms is correct."* - Yea, but they may not be optimal.   How do you expect us to explain when you don't show us the code of the algorithms or the benchmark?

Comment: Okay, just give me 5 mins.

Comment: Hint: never be to **sure** of anything in programming.

Comment: Nearly 7 minutes to sort 500k items? Your code (or something) is wrong -- it should take on the order of 1 second.

Comment: That should take less than a second with a proper merge sort implementation

Comment: @RahulTripathi - the titrias link shows a merge sort that uses copy back, which is significantly slower than a merge sort that alternates between two buffers without copy back. For arrays of integers, usually merge sort is within 10% of the speed of quick sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that merge() allocates temp[] based on a.length, when it should only be allocating temp = new int[high + 1 - low]. After this fix, references to temp[i] should be changed to temp[i-low].

With the current code, Java is having to allocate a 500,000 element array, even when it's only merging 1 even and 1 odd element (high + 1 - low == 2).

Example of a somewhat optimized top down merge sort that only allocates a temp buffer once, then uses mutually recursive functions to avoid copy back. In this example, ee is the ending index == a.length. This will sort 500,000 integers in less than 1/10th of a second, and 10,000,000 integers in less than 1.5 seconds.

```
static void MergeSort(int a[]) {
    if (a.length < 2)
        return;
    int []b = new int[a.length];
    MergeSortAtoA(a, b, 0, a.length);
}

static void MergeSortAtoA(int a[], int b[], int ll, int ee)
{
    if (ee - ll > 1) {
        int rr = (ll + ee)>>1;          // midpoint, start of right half
        MergeSortAtoB(a, b, ll, rr);
        MergeSortAtoB(a, b, rr, ee);
        Merge(b, a, ll, rr, ee);        // merge b to a
    }
}

static void MergeSortAtoB(int a[], int b[], int ll, int ee)
{
    if (ee - ll > 1) {
        int rr = (ll + ee)>>1;          //midpoint, start of right half
        MergeSortAtoA(a, b, ll, rr);
        MergeSortAtoA(a, b, rr, ee);
        Merge(a, b, ll, rr, ee);        // merge a to b
    } else if ((ee - ll) == 1) {
        b[ll] = a[ll];
    }
}

static void Merge(int []a, int []b, int ll, int rr, int ee) {
    int o = ll;                         // b[]       index
    int l = ll;                         // a[] left  index
    int r = rr;                         // a[] right index
    while(true){                        // merge data
        if(a[l] <= a[r]){               // if a[l] <= a[r]
            b[o++] = a[l++];            //   copy a[l]
            if(l < rr)                  //   if not end of left run
                continue;               //     continue (back to while)
            while(r < ee){              //   else copy rest of right run
                b[o++] = a[r++];
            }
            break;                      //     and return
        } else {                        // else a[l] > a[r]
            b[o++] = a[r++];            //   copy a[r]
            if(r < ee)                  //   if not end of right run
                continue;               //     continue (back to while)
            while(l < rr){              //   else copy rest of left run
                b[o++] = a[l++];
            }
            break;                      //     and return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it's only taking 1.333 second.